# Low Source Voltage: Driving 2V LED with 1.8V Signal, 5V Supply

Tags: led, mosfet

I am trying to get a 2V LED to to turn on. The CARRIER_STB# signal is a 1.8V signal. I have a 5V supply connected to the drain. Below is a screenshot of my that part of my circuit. EN_3V3_1V8 has been disconnected for the purposes of testing, but will have to be part of the design. Though that does not seem to be a problem.

I am measuring 1.4V at source, which is not enough to turn on the LED.

I have already tried 4 different N-channel MOSFETs.

The first one I tried was the DMN62D0U-13. When that didn't work, I checked and realized that I might have to pick something with a lower Rds.

Then I tried three more, and none of them worked. The FDN327N, NTR3C21NZT1G, and the NTR4501NT1G.

[image]

Comment: Can you be clearer about what you want to happen when the input signal is high and low?  When should the LED light? What do you want for the EN_3V3_1V8 output? It is not clear from the question as it is.

Comment: I would like EN_3V3_1V8 to be 5V high, and the LED to turn on when CARRIER_STB# is 1.8V high.

Comment: You can't do that with an N-FET. You will need to use a P-FET.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to use the N-FET in a high-side source-follower configuration, but without enough voltage drive to accomplish the task. Why? The source will be one gate-source voltage (Vgs) below the gate. Switching FETs have Vgs thresholds of between 1.2 to 4V. Even a low threshold FET like a BSS138 (Vgs=1.3V), the best source voltage you will see is 1.8-1.3=0.5V. Not what you're looking for.

If you add a second N-FET as an inverter / level shifter and use a P-FET on the high side, that will give the desired result. See below.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8VrYF.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: I don't follow why you need a second N-FET.

Comment: Using low-side drive, the gate becomes active-high. OP's signal is active-low. So it needs to be inverted.

Comment: Ok - that wasn't obvious to me from the question.

Comment: And OP wants active high, so I modified my answer. A basic 1.8 to 5V level conversion.

Comment: This makes sense. So there is no discrete MOSFET that has a Vgs threshold low enough to do a 1.8V to 5V conversion by itself? Would it be easier to just use a non-inverting buffer or level shifter?

Comment: Yes, a level-shifting buffer would work. You could also use a 5V load switch.

Comment: Thank you, @hacktastical

Answer (score 0):

You should put the LED in the drain circuit, not the source. Put the source pin straight to ground. The LED will light when the input is high.

Comment: I still need a signal to EN_3V3_1V8 though. How would I do that? The enable signal goes to 2 ICs. One takes 3.6V and the other takes 2V recommended. I wanted the 5V so I could step it down with a divider.